# Merkle Tree space complexity

Tags: complexity, hash-tree

When searching by using the Merkle tree, the time complexity is $\mathcal O(\log n)$ but I don't understand how space complexity is $\mathcal O(n)$. In my opinion, it should be also $\mathcal O(\log n)$. Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity assume that the Merkle tree is a [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). Let the number of data blocks is $n$ which are linked to the leaf nodes. Therefore the total number of tree nodes are $|nodes| = n + n/2+ \cdots +1$. If we assume that $n =2^k$ for simplicity than $$|nodes| = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^k = \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2-1} = 2^{k+1}-1 = 2n-1.$$ (refer sum of geometric series).

In total, we have $2n -1 $ nodes, that is together with the data blocks. As a result the number of nodes are $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

In another approach, you can consider the height of the tree as the search complexity, $h = c \log n$ then the maximum number of a binary tree with $h$ is $2^h-1 = 2^{c \log n}-1 = n 2^c-1 \in \mathcal{O}(n)$. Adding the data block will not change the complexity.

**Note:** In a complete binary tree, if we say that the root is level 1 then the $i$-th level contains $2^{i-1}$ nodes. Each level will contain a double of the previous level.

Comment: Thank you, I got the point. According to this, for example certificate revocation list is also growing 1 + 2 + 3 +...n so on. In this way, its complexity O(N^2). Is it correct?

Comment: No. For $n$ data elements the depth is $\log n$. For the certificate, you can go up to $\log n$ and the neighbors, the makes around $2 \log n$

Comment: @ kelalaka Sorry I dont understand how its space complexity is logn.Just adding new ones to list like 1,2,3...n?

Comment: Do you know how one can go to the root of a leaf in a complete binary tree? One travel parent of the parent of .... then the root. In the query, you asked for a data element that is linked to a lead. Now you need the neighbors for the validation of the hashes to the root. Since one can reach the root in $\log n$ step then the number of elements need to be transferred can not pass $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$

Comment: I got it but for CRL it is not a binary tree

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Certificate Revocation List (CRL) calculations in another question to be asked separately with a reference. If we assume that it is just a chained list then it can require at most $n$ elements. Why do you think that it is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$

Comment: @ kelalaka I thought that I should be add 1+2+3..+n then o(n^2) but I misthinking. its size just n, it should be o(n). Thank you so much

Comment: how can i compute verification cost? For example i have 5 revoked certificate and i would like to find corresponding verification cost. I know it is o(logn).But for 5 revoked certificate, should i calculate like log5?

Comment: @jhdm is this for CRL or Merkle tree?

Comment: Actuallt both of them. But if ı want to store revoked certificates in sorted merkle tree, verification cost is o(logn). However ı would like to draw a graph for that. But i dont know how can i find corresponding verification cost value for 5 revoked certificate

Comment: Have you ever heard of graphviz? If one uses the linear approach it is $\mathcal O(n)$

Comment: @ graphviz consider revoke certificate kept in sorted merkle tree. So i have five revoked certificate in sorted merkle tree. What should be corresponding verification cost for 5 revoked certificate. I know merkle tree verification cost is ologn. It should be log5 for 5 revoked certificate. Is it correct?

Comment: @kelalaka your sum is incorrect. $1$ + $2$ + $2^2$ + ... + $2^{k-1}$ + $2^k$ has in total $k+1$ terms. Hence, the sum of series should be $2^{k+1} - 1$. This will then lead to total terms as $ 2n - 1 $